# How do I create a formula that will count all the "x" in a list, then give me a total for amount paid based on amount of "x"?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I have a list aside for a staff party where we have a running total of amount paid at the bottom, and are indicating who is attending by placing an X next to their name. I would like it to be so that if I put an X next to the name, that it updates the total. I have no idea how to even attempt to do this, please help!

Comment: It’s a bit unclear what the “x” represents. On the one hand, you want to get the total paid based on the x’s, but on the other hand, you’ve stated “x” represents those who are attending. So which is it? Does “x” mean they’re attending, or that they’ve paid (or both)? Either way, you’d probably want to use either SUMIF or COUNTIF x *rate*.

Comment: DjC, apologies. X means both essentially, but it is just tracking who has paid

Comment: As in, X is just a tick next to a name to say they've paid

Comment: if the total is the amount of members, then use countif. if the total is the amount paid total, then use sumif.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways this can be achieved, depending on how you've setup your data. Without seeing what you've tried so far, here's one very basic example:

[image: staff_event.png]
**Figure 1:** Staff event payment summary

In this example, there's a set rate per person (input in cell D1) and each employee can bring additional guests (input in column C).

The first formula in cell D4 `=IF(B4="x",1+C4,0)` basically means that if an "x" has been input in cell B4 to indicate the employee has paid, it will return 1 for the employee plus the number of additional guests input in cell C4; and, if no "x" has been input in cell B4, it will return 0.

The formula is then copied down in column D for all employees in the list. This column represents the count of all persons paid/attending, with a total at the bottom in cell D19 `=SUM(D4:D18)`.

Lastly, the formula to calculate the total amount paid ($) in cell D20 `=D19*D1` is the ***total people attending * rate per person***.

I hope that helps get you started. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

More details are needed to better understand if you want AMOUNT or NUMBER as well as how your data are set up. Here's a solution using `COUNTIF`. Up to you to decide if you want to display the number and/or the amount paid. Solution for both below.

| **Employee** | **Paid** |
| --- | --- |
| A |  |
| B | x |
| C | x |
| D |  |
| E | x |
| F |  |
| **Total Paid** | **3** |
| **Amount Paid** | **$30.00** |

Total Paid formula:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B7,"x")
```

Amount Paid formula (same as total paid, multiply by n)

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B7,"x")*10
```